# solve derivative of summation on Maple

Tags: sum, maple, derivative

Is there any way to solve the derivative of summation on maple.
For the example,

```
y := qr->(1-qn-(sum(qn[j]-delta*qr, j))-c[r])*qr+(wn-c)*(qn+sum(qn[j], j))
```

I took the first partial derivative w.r.t qr, and I think the result was correct

```
diff(y(qr), qr)
```

But, when I solve the result of the derivative, the Maple did not give me any result.

```
solve(diff(y(qr), qr) = 0, qr)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you requested from **solve** depends on the number of terms in the summation. You haven't specified that. If you don't know that, you can specify it by symbols. Change the second arguments of both **sum**s from simply **j** to **j= a..b**. I did this, and then I got a simple answer from **solve**.

Comment: Thanks, It works.. @carl-love Is there any way to use condition in the summation ? for example `qn[i]+sum(qn[j],i!=j)`

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that without having definite limits of summation. How about formally accepting my Answer?